# Stop BackgroundService when app in background

Tags: android, android-fragments, background-service

I have a background service method that called frequently for updated application data.
I have a Activity in which multiple fragments are  display according to user navigation.
I just start service when application is started from my dashboard activity in which i am showing fragments.Now i just want to stop service when user exit from app.I have code for stop service in onDestroy() of my activity,but it never got called when user press android mobile home button and exit from app.

below my code in service -

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    callAsynchronousTask();
    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: You could not intercept the Home Button but you could figure out if the Home button is pressed. I had answer that a long time ago, just search for intercepting Home Button press.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onDestroy()` will only called when you close your app or close your activity. when you press home button it does not call. If you still want service to stop when user press home button then you can override `onPause()` and stop service inside this, ***but when you open another activity service will stop again.***

Comment: yes i have try in both and facing same issue,any other way can you please suggest.

Comment: then you have to play around one flag which should be true when you are on Home Activity, and in that true condition, stop the service.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Activity` is not getting destroyed when you press the Home button! Try to implement your functionality in the `onPause` method or in some other point of an Activity's lifecycle that best fits your needs!

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: i just try in onPause but if when screen lock or when app navigate to next activity then on stop is being called and service stop.

Comment: i see Pavlos's answer correct based on what you asked, for an ultimate answer, you have to see the link and understand the activity lifecycle.

Comment: you are right but i just want to stop service when user press home button.So i just want to know if any other way to do that.

Comment: That's why i told you to study the Activity's Lifecycle! Because usually when you press the HomeButton your onPause or your onStop method is going to be called!

Comment: i was there before, for playing a background music, bottom line, when i searched, "home button pressed" specifically  is undetectable (OS constrain) because they don't want some app that abuse the mobile, imagine an app reopens itself when the user press home.